# Nextjs nginx docker configuration

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, npm, next.js

I'm trying to containerize next js app with nginx in docker. I have Dockerfile for nextjs app:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /my-space

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /my-space
COPY --from=builder /my-space/package.json .
COPY --from=builder /my-space/package-lock.json .
COPY --from=builder /my-space/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /my-space/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /my-space/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder /my-space/.next/static ./.next/static
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

I have Dockerfile for nginx:

```
# Base on offical NGINX Alpine image
FROM nginx:stable

# Remove any existing config files
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Copy config files
# *.conf files in conf.d/ dir get included in main config
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Expose the listening port
EXPOSE 80

# Launch NGINX
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

I have this nginx `default.conf` configuration:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

upstream nextjs_upstream {
  server frontend:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  server_tokens off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }

 location /_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }

  location /static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }

  location /_next {
      proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }

   location /_next/public {
      proxy_cache STATIC;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
    }

   location /_next/standalone {
      proxy_cache STATIC;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
    }

  location /public {
      proxy_cache STATIC;
      proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
      proxy_cache_valid 60m;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$ {
      add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
  }

  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass https://mydev.online/api;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

I build both nextjs app and nginx with needed tags and then run docker compose:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    frontend:
        image: myfront
        container_name: frontend
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
    nginx:
        image: nginx-custom
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

But the problem is that it's not working. In `next.config.json` I have:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        outputStandalone: true,
    },
```

But I also tried Dockerfile without it:

```
# Build Stage
FROM node:16-alpine AS BUILD_IMAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


# Production Stage
FROM node:16-alpine AS PRODUCTION_STAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/public ./public
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/node_modules ./node_modules
ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But both options doesn't work. I can open the site on 3000 port, but can't open nginx on 80 port because it gives a lot of errors when trying to access the paths on `/_next` and returns blank page, the same paths seem to work on 3000 port. What might be the problem here? 
P.S:
I tried this dockerfile and it also doesn't work (and some of its variations) because it gives error when building image because some modules are missing, or something like this (there are a lot of errors):

```
# Base on offical Node.js Alpine image
FROM node:alpine

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json before other files
# Utilise Docker cache to save re-installing dependencies if unchanged
COPY ./package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --production

# Copy all files
COPY ./ ./

# Build app
RUN npm run build

# Expose the listening port
EXPOSE 3000

# Run container as non-root (unprivileged) user
# The node user is provided in the Node.js Alpine base image
USER node

# Run npm start script when container starts
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

UPD:
I also tried setting `network_mode: host` in docker compose file to both nginx and frontend containers, and setting `localhost:3000` in default.conf to redirect to, but it also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that networking between the containers is not working. Might want to add linking and host in docker compose

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    frontend:
        image: myfront
        container_name: frontend
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
    nginx:
        image: nginx-custom
        ports:
            - 80:80
        links:
           - frontend
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

if you run next.js inside docker, you should specify the `HOSTNAME` after `PORT` in **dockerfile**:

```
ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"
```